# What could explain the fact that during 1976-80, I used to hear commercial jets make sonic booms while flying overhead?

Tags: boeing-747, airlines, noise, sonic-boom

I've read on this site & on Wikipedia that there have only been a couple of commercial jet planes in history that have broken the sound barrier--either in testing (without passengers) or during an unexpected descent.  However, during the period of 1976-80/81, when I lived fairly close to an international airport, I used to regularly hear commercial jets (I assume 747's) create sonic booms as they passed fairly low overhead. I now live even closer to a much bigger international airport, & never hear this. That's why I started to wonder why. & now that I've read that on record, it's only happened a couple of times, I'm even more curious of what the explanation could be. (It was Bradley Airport in CT, if that matters).

Comment: Hard to know what you actually heard but Bradley is also shared by the CT ANG. Military jets make all sorts of loud noises that aren’t common with commercial planes, maybe that’s part of the story?

Comment: Was the airport perhaps also used by the military or was there a nearby AF base?

Comment: If you can't tell the difference between what you heard and a gunshot or an explosion then it's a sonic boom. If it doesn't sound like a gunshot or explosion then it's not a sonic boom. If you really did hear a sonic boom perhaps you mistook it for a real gunshot?

Comment: When I was growing up in the 80s, we used to hear them from fighter jets going over head.  That stopped pretty soon after '87? '88?  they still happen off the coast; but not so much over land any more: https://www.wmbfnews.com/2020/02/28/neighbors-little-river-longs-area-report-homes-shaking-heres-what-we-know/

Comment: It's not quite true that commercial planes have only broken the sound barrier in testing or unexpected descents. There were many scheduled supersonic flights on Concorde - which actually started flying to Washington in 1976. But it was only allowed to go supersonic over the ocean, to avoid hitting people on the ground with sonic booms, so that probably wasn't what you heard. There was also a Soviet supersonic passenger jet, but that's probably not it either.

Comment: I've read that military aircraft often use the Death Valley National Park as a place to try low-altitude supersonic flight. One even crashed a few months ago while doing so.

Comment: @slebetman I'd compare it more to a (large) cannon shot than a normal gunshot. It's much louder than a normal gun, at least in my experience. Even from a significant distance, it can easily shake a building.

Comment: @user6030, please post a link or reference to where you heard this.  You can’t routinely fly supersonic in CONUS, let alone in National Parks.  I have done several Red Flag exercises operating in remote MOAs and it was a no-no even there.

Comment: @slebetman, there is a pretty big difference in sound between a gunshot and a sonic boom.

Comment: Opinion based and not a definitively answerable question

Comment: In the early-to-mid 1960's, the Air National Guard at Fort Wayne, Indiana's Baer Field did some low-level supersonic exercises on a regular basis. Living just a mile away (somewhat out-in-the-country), we saw the jets, and felt the sonic booms. So low-level supersonic flight was evidently permissible in those days, for military aircraft. And a sonic boom is unmistakeable, after you've heard such.

Comment: Two examples of the same sonic boom events from different distances: https://youtu.be/otfBviE1G3k at 1:40 and https://youtu.be/VBlIvghQTlI at 0:30. These are doubled as there are two rockets making the booms. Do these sound familiar?

Comment: All of the sonic booms I ever heard in the 60's, when they were fairly common in western Washington, made double or in some cases, triple booms.  They were easily distinguishable from gunshots and explosions, both of which were also quite common in my rural area at the time. When there were multiple super-sonic aircraft nearby, it was often indistinguishable from thunder.  A super-sonic rocket might produce a single boom, due it's envelope.  I suppose more modern planes might have only single booms.

Comment: @jwdonahue A WW2 German Panzer 88mm made a double report.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I don't doubt it. First you'd hear the round go over head, then you'd hear the muzzle blast that followed it.  For aircraft however, it appears the cause has to do with the leading and trailing edges of the aircraft: https://www.google.com/search?q=double+sonic+boom+from+aircraft.

Comment: @jwdonahue I understood it was a characteristic of the actual firing. Perhaps shell departing and pressure wave thereafter. Not mentioned [here](https://wiki2.org/en/8.8_cm_KwK_43) but it's interesting.

Comment: It sounded like an explosion.  & I believe Bradley shares their space with the National Airforce.  But I definitely remember these jets looking like normal commercial jets--very big & white.

Answer (score 38):

Note that 747's and other jumbo jets operating out of Bradley could not have produced sonic booms because they do not fly above the speed of sound (they only do 500 to 550 MPH at high altitude cruise) and, in any case, far slower than that (~250 MPH) when near the ground as for landing and takeoff.

Therefore, whatever it was you heard, it was assuredly not a sonic boom from a passenger plane. The last time these commonly occurred was in the 1950's and '60s when the US Air Force flew mock bombing missions across the United States in supersonic bombers at low altitude, to train the pilots and crews for similar missions against targets in the USSR.

Although sonic booms were essentially outlawed over populated zones in the early 1960's, in your case they apparently did happen during flight tests of the F-22 Raptor in your location, which is very interesting! Thanks for @reirab's  detective work which uncovered this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110430/discussion-on-answer-by-niels-nielsen-what-could-explain-the-fact-that-during-19).

Comment: Can you advise where the comment re F22s by Reirab comes from. I don't see his name or F22 mentioned on this page or in the now removed comments to your post. Sounds interesting.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, he said it was originally posted & answered on the aviation stack exchange.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Reirab spoke of Tennessee & OP here is talking about Connecticut, I don't see how they could be talking about the same thing.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I searched the site but alas can find no mention. It sounds worth commenting on in more detail in an answer.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, search for reirab under "users" (tab on left), you'll find him.

Comment: @Russell McMahon What I used to see was definitely not the F22!  Looked absolutely nothing like it!  It was big & white! I think it may have been the Concorde (See below).  Only thing that may not fit, according to comments, is that it was always going due SW.  (Apparently, it flew to Kennedy airport, but I suppose it may have not been able to fly directly in that direction for some reason).

Answer (score 14):

It was either not a sonic boom, or it was not a commercial jet. As Niels has pointed out, civilian aircraft are prohibited from operating faster than 250 knots Indicated Airspeed below 10,000 feet MSL in most cases. You would have to get special permission from FAA leadership (not ATC controllers) to otherwise perform such a stunt.

> **§91.117 Aircraft speed.**
> (a) Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator, no person may operate an aircraft below 10,000 feet MSL at an indicated airspeed of more than 250 knots (288 m.p.h.).

At those speeds, you can hear the aircraft coming. But, the sound seems to be much more intense and at a lower (bass) frequency after it has passed rather than when it is approaching. Like hearing a race car at full-tilt passing you on the sidelines. Much more rumble-like after passing due in part to Doppler effect and the aircraft being closer to the ground when landing.

Speaking of closer to the ground, modern Noise Abatement Procedures have made it so large turbine powered aircraft avoid overflying populated areas at low altitudes. The aircraft will climb quicker to altitude, descend later from altitude, or turn away sooner, thereby reducing the effect of aircraft noise in neighboring communities.

The FAA and ICAO has taken further steps to reduce the actual noise produced by aircraft according to [FAA.gov](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/airport_aircraft_noise_issues/levels/),

> *“In 1990, Congress passed the Aviation Noise and Capacity Act, which required that by the year 2000 all jet and large turboprop aircraft at civilian airports be Stage 3.”*

Furthermore, [FAA.gov](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/airport_aircraft_noise_issues/) goes on to say!

> *”The FAA has undertaken a phase out of older, noisier civil aircraft, resulting in some stages of aircraft no longer being in the fleet. Currently within the contiguous US, civil jet aircraft over 75,000 pounds maximum take-off weight must meet Stage 3 and Stage 4 to fly. In addition, aircraft at or under 75,000 pounds maximum take-off weight must meet Stage 2, 3, or 4 to operate within the U.S. In addition, by December 31, 2015, all civil jet aircraft, regardless of weight must meet Stage 3 or Stage 4 to fly within the contiguous U.S. Both Stage 1 and Stage 2 helicopters are allowed to fly within the U.S.”*

Small military jets (not transport or cargo) sometimes operate at higher speeds along specific routes or in specific areas. Though, even at subsonic speeds, the effect can be quite jarring. When close to the ground, it is almost like a fighter jet is sneaking up on you in silent mode until it passes you in a great and sudden cacophony of sound. You don’t hear it coming, then **BOOM!** Unfortunately, that is still not a sonic boom. Just aircraft noise with a perceived increase in intensity as it thunders past you.

In the case of engine noise, you will continue to hear the noise as the aircraft fades into the distance. Like rolling thunder instead of the bomb-like or cannon-like dull thud of an explosion that is a sonic boom.

Comment: Actually you can hear those fighter jets coming.  I can't say that it NEVER happens that one "sneaks up" on you, but I get overflown several times a year (not fun when you're on a nervous horse!) and have always been able to hear them at least far enough in advance to say "Oh, crap!".

Comment: @jamesqf - That really depends on the speed and the altitude. I have been at sporting events, airports, airfields, air shows, large lakes, Gulf of Mexico, and military bases when a fighter jock has decided to make a low-level, high-speed flyby. Whether it is the backside of Fort Hood or the city side of Soldier Field, a fighter staying barely subsonic less than 1000 feet over your head can sneak up on you. Heck, you would be surprised how well a hovering Longbow behind a berm can blend into the background noise. I’ve heard GAU-8s on the range without ever hearing the airplane.

Comment: @jamesqf In the UK, some of the more mountainous regions are regularly used for low-level flight training.  One day, I and a friend were standing on top of a small hill in the Lake District to observe a partial solar eclipse.  Groups of Tornadoes were flying past at regular intervals, and we tried to spot them all while waiting.  In one group, we spotted one of a pair against a hillside, then tried to find its wingman; I saw it coming directly at us while my friend was staring in the wrong direction.  It was silent until about a second before it went overhead…  then **ROAR**.

Comment: @Dean F.: "less than 1000 feet over your head"? Knock a zero off that, and you'd be close to what some of them do around here.  One place I go a lot has long, narrow meadows running down to a lake, and I've seen them following the meadows, lower than the trees to either side.

Comment: I agree with your answer, @DeanF., however the things you're quoting all seem to be in effect from 1990 onward, while the OP mentioned a 1975-80 time frame. I agree that it absolutely was _not_ commercial airline traffic creating sonic booms, but references of regs from the late 70s would make a strong case stronger.

Comment: @ Niels Nielsen I looked up F-22 rafter.  Definitely not what I saw!  They looked like commercial jets--very big & white.

Answer (score 12):

If you lived near an international airport with commercial traffic, then it couldn't possibly have been sonic booms, as others have noted. What you likely have heard is jet noise.

Jet noise has been known to be notoriously bad. If you google sound scale, jet noise is pretty much [always near the top](https://transportgeography.org/?page_id=5796). That's one of the primary reasons why [city airports](https://www.toronto.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/9936-porter-cs100-aircraft-noise-assessment.pdf) haven't flourished as well as people have thought back in the 70s. That being said, leaps and bounds have been made since the first commercial jet airplanes.

[image: jet noise]

<sub>Ref: https://aqrc.ucdavis.edu/sites/g/files/dgvnsk1671/files/inline-files/UC%20Davis%20Noise%20101_0.pdf</sub>

The above chart shows the sideline noise of narrow-body jet (including turbojet and turbofan) powered airplanes measured in [EPNdB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPNdB#:%7E:text=Effective%20perceived%20noise%20in%20decibels,noise%20exposure%20from%20an%20airport.), which is a scale for Perceived Noisiness Level. As you can see, there has been 15-20dB reduction between what's certified in the mid-90s and 70s. A 20dB reduction corresponds to a whopping **99%** reduction in sound energy, and a **75%** reduction in terms of [hearing perceptibility](https://www.epd.gov.hk/epd/noise_education/web/ENG_EPD_HTML/m1/intro_4.html#:%7E:text=While%20there%20are%20variations%20in,by%20the%20normal%20human%20ear.).

Much of the noise reduction has been through the engines themselves, as shown below. For new aircraft, we've reached a point where airframe noise is comparable or larger than engine noise for noise testing.

[image: engine noise]

<sub>Ref: https://aqrc.ucdavis.edu/sites/g/files/dgvnsk1671/files/inline-files/UC%20Davis%20Noise%20101_0.pdf</sub>

Note: Concorde SST is a definite abheration. It's certified in the late 80s and has a sideline noise of [112 EPNdB](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/aircraft_noise_levels/media/nonuscert_appendix_02.xls). That's when its speed is subsonic.

Comment: I note concorde wasn't on your sound scale, probably because they would have needed to make the y-axis logarithmic

Comment: @jamiec dB is already a logarithmic unit

Comment: Lol, true! Forgot

Comment: Sorry 4 delay in checking back 4 answers- didn't expect so many! Thanks every1! (1st time here).To answer people's questions, I was living in Barkhamsted, CT-small town in NW CT not far from MA border. It is in mountainous area--very close to a ski mntn. I recall 1 time very clearly-certainly looked like a commercial jet to me. I'd hear them coming but then just as it would fly directly overhead (low), I'd hear a deafening, cracking BOOM that I could feel in my body. Always made me jump. I recall my older brother saying "sonic boom". I've seen many fighter jets. These were much bigger & white.

Answer (score 5):

You may have been hearing the Concorde reaching supersonic speed after its takeoff from the JFK and Dulles airports.

I heard them frequently while on Cape Cod during the summer months. Interesting [studies](https://books.google.com/books?id=xjpdM5nxuYoC&pg=PA1057&lpg=PA1058&dq=concorde+airliner+nantucket+sonic+boom&source=bl&ots=ce4csSUPJB&sig=ACfU3U1CqCOCGoshag_aTsdbEfadk313-A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBnemx07vqAhUphHIEHSHOAO0Q6AEwDnoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=concorde%20airliner%20nantucket%20sonic%20boom&f=false) were done about this phenomenon and its effect on the population.

Comment: Concorde is(was) only allowed supersonic over water : but I'm not clear how far offshore it had to be. Boom may have been audible for a few tens of miles...

Comment: And Bradley Airport is 80km from the nearest sea (Long Island Sound) and about 200km from Cape Cod (further than Boston is), so if Concorde was conspicuous there it would have been apparent to a large population.

Comment: Now the Concorde idea is interesting.  I was only a kid, & I just remember "very big & white" as the physical description.  & when I looked it up on Wikipedia, there's a Concorde that flew from 1977-1982 that doesn't give a location, except where it was scrapped more than a decade after its last flight (which is curious). Perhaps this Concorde was what I used to see: "211 F-BVFD[27] 10 February 1977 27 May 1982 5814 Scrapped in 1994. A small section of the fuselage remains at Le Bourget, France and the nose cone was sold to an American collector" (Wikipedia)

Comment: It was always going Southwest, btw.

Answer (score 5):

## What would real sonic booms have been like?

The other answers do a good job of explaining how commercial airliners have gotten quieter over the years and how you were probably hearing jet noise, not sonic booms. But how do you know it wasn't a sonic boom? What would it have been like to live under regular sonic booms? Well the only way to know that for sure would be to regularly fly supersonic flights over a heavily populated area and then study how people responded. Doing that would be a bad idea at best and madness at worst. So of course it was tried.

Oklahoma City *volunteered* to be the test city for a [1964 test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma_City_sonic_boom_tests). For six months, the Air Force flew supersonic flights over the city to see how much it annoyed residents. It wasn't subtle. [The final report](https://www.norc.org/PDFs/publications/NORCRpt_101.pdf) tried its best to put a positive spin on the results, but there was no hiding that there was a fundamental difference between jet noise and a sonic boom. While 70% of residents reported hearing airplane noise, 99% reported hearing sonic booms (Table 78 of the final report). And while 6% of residents reported being annoyed by airplane noise, 25% said they were bothered by the sonic booms (Table 79).

> Over 80% of all respondents said they could always distinguish a sonic boom from other noises... Most of the people who can t always recognize a boom said they thought it was either an explosion or a thunder storm. It is interesting to note that
> the distant area residents most often failed to recognize the boom and wondered if it was a storm or explosion

So if the sound you heard sounded like an airplane, it probably wasn't a sonic boom. You'd expect to hear something more like thunder or an explosion.

A whopping 40% of area residents reported damage to their homes. In one of the report's most *optimistic* sections, it tries to put a positive spin on the damage claims:

> Direct scientific evidence indicates that the Oklahoma City booms did
> not cause any significant damage to the local test houses, which were
> instrumented by the FAA to measure physical effects of booms. Large
> numbers of residents, however, felt their houses had been damaged.
> Over 40% overall felt this way; while 50% of the annoyed and 86% of
> the actual complainers also felt this way. This clearly suggests that
> belief in alleged damage increased annoyance and complaint activity.

So even through the positive spin of the report, you see a picture of people who endured sonic booms that they thought were explosions and that they said caused damage to their homes. It sounds like what you heard wasn't quite this intense and was more likely to be jet noise.